# AJAX + JQuery synchronization issue

Tags: jquery, ajax

From another method I am calling the method below, the problem is its always returning 0 while data[4] is not 0. If javascript is single threaded how come there is a synchronization problem here? if not can you please explain and suggest a fix.

```
function GetVMData(url_s){
    var cpu_USG = 0;
    $.ajax({
           url: url_s,
           crossDomain: true, 
           dataType: 'jsonp',
           success: function(data) {
                   cpu_USG = data[4];
           },
           error: function(xhr, status, error) { 
               alert('failed')
            } 
       });
    return cpu_USG;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use [jquery deferreds](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/):

```
// the function definition
function GetVMData(url_s){
    return $.ajax({
           url: url_s,
           crossDomain: true, 
           dataType: 'jsonp',
           error: function(xhr, status, error) { 
               alert('failed')
            } 
       }).pipe(function(data) { return data[4]; });
}

// function call example
GetVMData('some url').done(function(cpu_USG) {
    alert(cpu_USG);
});
```

This solution is **MUCH** better than making ajax request synchronous.